# Flip animation in Recylerview

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Requirement is simple i.e add flip animation to the Recylerviewrow on click of a button and load different sets of data.But the problem is i am not getting proper resource of flip animation for Recylerview.

[This is the requirement only flip animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ0zJ.gif)

I have tried this code to edit
https://github.com/patrick-iv/Enter-animation-demo

**Animation code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:delay="15%"
    android:animationOrder="normal" />
```

**item_animation_fall_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_medium">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-20%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="105%"
        android:fromYScale="105%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%" />
</set>
```

**The animation added in the class:**

```
private void runLayoutAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final AnimationItem item) {
        final Context context = recyclerView.getContext();

        final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, item.getResourceId());

        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    }
```

When  I am trying to change the item_animation_fall_down.xml to add the flip animation then the app is crashing saying

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator**
```

Flip animation code [Flip animation](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/android-flipa-card-animation-exlpained/)